# Possibly unhandled rejection -- Error when creating a form with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, firebase, angularjs-q

I created this simple web application to put data into a firebase database. The problem is that I get a error when I open the webpage in my browser. This is the error I get

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: {} angular.js:14324
```

Also when I press the sumbit button the first time with no data in the fields it displays the same error as shown above. Then when I press the button again it does submit the empty fields to the database. I think angular finds it a problem that the fields are empty. Am I missing something? Putting text in the fields works fine and it also submits to the database. It's just with empty fields that their are problems.

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);
app.controller("SampleCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("messages");
    $scope.loading = true;
    $firebaseArray(ref).$loaded().then(function(){
        $scope.loading = false;
        document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
    });
    $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref);
    $scope.addMessage = function() {
        $scope.messages.$add({
            name: $scope.name,
            company: $scope.company,
            reason: $scope.reason,
            wayofcontact: $scope.wayofcontact,
        });
        $scope.name = '';
        $scope.company = '';
        $scope.reason = '';
        $scope.wayofcontact = '';
        document.getElementById("name").focus();
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sampleApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
    [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
        display: none !important;
    }
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="SampleCtrl" ng-cloak >
    <div class="container" ng-view>
        <div ng-show="loading">
            Loading...
        </div>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="message in messages | filter:{name: '!!'}">
                <h1>{{message.name}}</h1>
                <p>
                    Bedrijf: {{message.company}}<br>
                    Reden: {{message.reason}}<br>
                    Email/telefoon: {{message.wayofcontact}}<br>
                </p>
                <button ng-click="messages.$remove(message)" class="btn btn-danger">Verwijder verzoek</button>
                <br><br>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form ng-submit="addMessage()" novalidate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="name" placeholder="Naam" autofocus required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="namecolleague" placeholder="Naam collega" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="company" placeholder="Bedrijf" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <textarea rows="3" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="reason" placeholder="Reden van bellen" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="wayofcontact" placeholder="Email of nummer" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Message</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.1.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

This error appears to be something that was added as a part of the $qProvider that is used to configure $q

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$qProvider

did a search on the error since it didn't look familiar but looks like you can just disable the feature in a config block with this provider

```
app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);
```

I guess the only other thing to add is something that returns a promise here must be failing but has no error handler registered.

Comment: This works and hides the message. But still when I press the submit button first time the empty form does not submit to the firebase database. And then when I press it a second time it does submit the empty data to the firebase database. I could record a video of me doing it for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Attach an error handler to the `$loaded()` promise chain:

```
$firebaseArray(ref).$loaded().then(function(){
    $scope.loading = false;
    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    throw e;
});
```

If the error is coming from that `.then` block, the console will show more detail.

AngularJS 1.6.0 has made errors in `.then` blocks less noisy. Unfortunately some details are lost. AngularJS 1.6.1 will have better error messages.

> Due to [c9dffde](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e13eeabd7e34a78becec06cfbe72c23f2dcb85f9), possibly unhandled rejected promises will be logged to the `$exceptionHandler`. Normally, that means that an error will be logged to the console, but in tests `$exceptionHandler` will (by default) re-throw any exceptions. Tests that are affected by this change (e.g. tests that depend on specific order or number of messages in `$exceptionHandler`) will need to handle rejected promises.

-- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to v1.6 - $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$q).

See also:

- [AngularJS Issue #14631  $q: Unhandled rejections should not be stringified](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14631)
- [AngularJS Issue #15527 Add traceback to unhandled promise rejections](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/15527)

Comment: Their is no issue with loading the data. It has to do something with the submitting of the form to the database.

Comment: You stated the error message occurs on the open of the browser as well as on the first submit of the form. That would indicate a possible error in the $load chain. Add an error catcher to the $add chain to see if there is a problem in that chain. Or revert to Angular 1.5.x to get better error messages.

Comment: I found out wat was causing it to fail the first time. The first time the fields are empty and when I sumbit I set all the fields to '' with $scope.name = ''; now when I run the script I put nothing in every field so it does submit with no data.